# Song in Yes Man as Carl runs up the stairs before Jumper

Tags: soundtrack, yes-man

I recently watched Yes Man and I recognized a song but I have no idea what it's called. It's the one that plays as Carl is running up the stairs to save the suicidal guy. It's NOT Jumper, it's the song before Jumper. There are drums playing over the song in the scene but I don't think they are in the original song.

Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=cBz5IdxITP8#t=18

The song only lasts for ten seconds, anyone who can help, please do! This is killing me!

Thanks!

Comment: I am probably the last person on Earth with iOS5, but if you have the newer iOS (or a Droid) download the app called Shazam and hold it up to your computer while you play the clip.  It should identify it pretty quickly.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried, naturally. As I said, there's drums playing over the song in the scene so Shazam can't pick it up. It's also not a well known song so Shazam may not have it in their music library.

Comment: It just sounds like the drum portion of *Jumper* to me, maybe 25 seconds into the song. I'm talking the actual song sung by Third Eye Blind, not the one being sung by Jim Carrey in the movie.

Comment: No, definitely not, sorry. I've looked up the Third Eye Blind version and it's definitely not a snippet of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Found it!

The version in the movie is slightly sped up and altered. I knew it from a recognised it from a Chrome Experiment that I had seen years ago.

Song: Danger Mouse & Daniele Luppi - 3 Dreams of Black starring Norah Jones

Youtube Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uy4em4pYHz0

Chrome Experiment: http://www.ro.me/

Comment: I must wait until tomorrow.